# Django Authorization: Redirecting to a 403 page

Tags: python, django, web

My problem is:

In default Django, When a logged-out user clicks on or selects a link that they do not have permission to see (as defined by Django) they get redirected to the administrative login page by default. How would I change this redirecting so it gives the user a 403 forbidden instead of just prompting them with a login?

I specifically used the decorator @permission_required on the view that would need permission to see. Here's what a typical view would look like in my views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

...

    @permission_required('erl.compile')
    def compile_robot(request, robot_id):
        robot = models.Robot.objects.get(id=robot_id, deleted=False)
        with set_message(request, "Compile Successful"):
            robot.compile()
        return redirect('robot', robot_id=robot_id)
```

So, my question is if I could somehow get the @permission_required decorator to redirect to a 403 page instead of a login screen.

I'm using Django version `1.8`  Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@permission_required('erl.compile',raise_exception=True)
```

Comment: A documentation link so as where to import `@permission_required` decorator would be great.